DBI cpan install fails
Trying to install DBI.pm using
cpan install DBI

under bash-4.2 fails on several linux platforms including raspberrypi.
On a GoDaddy server a lot of commands go well until
gcc -c (many options)  Perl.c

Then
In file included from Perl.xs:7:

Perl.xs: In function ‘dbi_get_state’:
DBIXS.h:498:32: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(PerlInterpreter *, CV *)’ {aka ‘void (*)(struct            +interpreter *, struct cv *)’} to ‘dbistate_t ** (*)(PerlInterpreter *)’ {aka ‘struct dbistate_st ** (*)(struct interpreter *)’} [-Wcast-   +function-type]
             dbi_state_lval_p = (_dbi_state_lval_t)CvXSUB(cv);               \
                                ^
DBIXS.h:506:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘_DBISTATE_DECLARE_COMMON’
 # define DBISTATE_DECLARE _DBISTATE_DECLARE_COMMON
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Perl.xs:13:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBISTATE_DECLARE’
 DBISTATE_DECLARE;
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Complete output can be seen at
Real-World-Systems.com/installDBI.240605.godaddy.txt
I had been using DBI,DBD and CGI on a Midphase server. They suddenly migrated to StackCP and it seems that they cannot get these modules back.
I tried a cpan install from my account at midphase but I do not have access to gcc.
On a raspberry pi, Linux dapi2 5.10.103+ #1529 Tue Mar 8 12:19:18 GMT 2022 armv6l GNU/Linux
I started with
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI'

local::lib
again all went well until
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c  --manyoptions  Perl.c

when the sam error was reported.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Can anyone duplicate or refute this problem?

@Luis Mochan  Have you tried using
[cpanm(cpanminus)] ? 1
